# Increase the width of the product table in the order confirmation template

Tags: products, table, confirmation

I'm trying to help my friend out who has a Magento Store, (2.3.6). I'm a little new to Magento but am experienced with PHP, HTML, CSS.

Order confirmation emails are coming through badly formatted and I'm trying to increase the width of the table containing product information. See the image below. Basically I want the area in the red-dashed box to fill the available space. I would also like the QTY field to be on the same level as the Item description and Price.

Which file do I need to edit in order to set the width of that table?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually, layouts in Magento 2 are edited in the .xml files.

Emails are found in app/code/Magento(or your theme)/Sales/view/frontend/layout/

Then you need to find the block which contains the order items.

Other paths that you may be interested are:
app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml
vendor\magento\module_sales\view\frontend\templates\order\items.phtml
app/design/frontend/{ThemeVendorname}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Sales/templates/order/items.phtml
app/design/frontend/{ThemeVendorname}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_view.xml

Comment: The last two of of those file references don't marry up with the structure of the template installed, unfortunately. I've checked out the first 2, though, and they don't seem to be the layout of the order confirmation, and there's certainly nothing dictating the width of the table.

Is there a CSS file for any of this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instruction to edit the email layout. Its just a HTML which you need to modify.

[https://magefan.com/blog/customize-magento-2-email-templates#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20manage%20the,the%20Add%20New%20Template%20button](https://magefan.com/blog/customize-magento-2-email-templates#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20manage%20the,the%20Add%20New%20Template%20button).